# Does Apple HIG enforce that tapping a cell in a UITableView should have the same action in Normal and Edit mode?

Tags: ios, user-interface, uitableview

I have a UITableView showing a Weekly Planner. 
In normal view if the user taps on a cell it opens the activity in a non-editable view. In the Edit mode however tapping a cell allows the user to replace an existing activity with another one from a list of activities. The Edit mode also has some extra "Add ..." cells that allow users to add activities from a list to their schedule.

While it seems to be intuitive from my experience while testing, I want to know if Apple does not allow this or recommends against this. I couldn't find a direct reference in HIG to something like this.

Has anyone ever faced any issue with something like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's allowed to have different actions in edit and normal modes. In fact, some of Apple's apps do this. The Contacts app for instance will dial the tapped phone number in normal mode but edit it in edit mode. And there is a new Add button to add new numbers.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation. You're right about similar behavior on Contacts page. I think I'm good to go!

Comment: Alarms tab in the Clock app behaves this way as well!

Comment: @KaanDedeoglu Actually in Alarm Clock the cells aren't touchable at all in Normal Mode. But in my case 2 different views open up depending on the Mode.